# How to use REST API Administration Services of IBM MobileFirst on SoapUI

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to access the below URL from SoapUI which **Retrieves metadata of a specific adapter**.

https://www.example.com/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/myruntime/adapters/myadapter?locale=de_DE

When I am accessing this URL from SoapUI. I am not sure what to give in its header and
I get

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

But when I use it in browser it asks me to login to worklightconsole so this would be granting access as a admin.

Can some one help me in understanding how to use the above URL in SoapUI and get success response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are getting 401 Unauthorized, it clearly says that you are trying to access the URL without providing any authorization information. Can you find out from SoapUI where you can provide the authorization information for the request? Basically you can select the 'Basic Auth' and provide the user name and password. For Http client like Postman there is an authorization tab, where you can select the authorization type and then username and password. It should be similar for SoapUI too